# Pandas Dataframe count occurrences that only happen immediately

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame 'A'

| Index | 1or0 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 |
| 3 | 0 |
| ... | ... |
| 8 | 0 |
| 9 | 1 |
| 10 | 1 |
| ... | ... |

I want to count how many times the zero (or 1) occurs in directly afterwards in the index column and write that into a new dataframe 'B' below:

| StartNum | EndNum | Size |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 8 | 8 | 1 |
| 9 | 10 | 2 |

What is the fastest or best way to do this? just iterate like I would do with an array or is there a better way using pandas?

Comment: Can you share the implementation you suggested of "iterating as you'd do with an array"? Would be easier to get help from there ...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, use this :

```
# is there any 0<>1 transition? if so, then cumsum!
ser = A["1or0"].ne(A["1or0"].shift().bfill()).cumsum()
​
B = (
        A.groupby(ser, as_index=False)
            .agg({"Index": ["first", "last", "count"]})
            .set_axis(["StartNum", "EndNum", "Size"], axis=1)
    )
```

​
Output:

```
print(B)

   StartNum  EndNum  Size
0         1       3     3
1         4       7     4
2         8       8     1
3         9      10     2
```

**Update (based on comments**) :

```
B = (
        A.groupby(ser, as_index=False)
            .agg({"Index": ["first", "last", "count"],
                  "1or0": "unique"})
            .set_axis(["StartNum", "EndNum", "Size", "Value"], axis=1)
            .assign(Value= lambda d: d["Value"].astype(str).str.strip("[]"))
    )

print(B)
​
   StartNum  EndNum  Size Value
0         1       3     3     0
1         4       7     4     1
2         8       8     1     0
3         9      10     2     1
```

*DataFrame used :*

```
print(A)

   Index  1or0
0      1     0
1      2     0
2      3     0
3      4     1
4      5     1
5      6     1
6      7     1
7      8     0
8      9     1
9     10     1
```

Comment: What are the "first","last","count" doing in the .agg function? How does this work?

Comment: As their names suggest, they return the first, last and number of elements of each group. You need to read the doc : https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: i see thank you. What would I need to change, so that B shows also the Value that was counted?

Comment: I made an update. Let me know if it's what you need ;)

Comment: wow thank you :) Im trying to learn those sophisticated pandas functions